# Entity Framework 4.1, Table Per Type Inheritance and Lookup Tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type

Using table per type inheritance is it possible to have the same data with the same key in more than one of the derived types?

e.g.

Base Type :

```
[Table("BaseType")]
public abstract class BaseType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Type A :

```
[Table("DerivedTypeA")]    
public class DerivedTypeA : BaseType {}
```

Derived Type B :

```
[Table("DerivedTypeB")]
public class DerivedTypeB : BaseType {}
```

Along with a number of types that are either `DerivedTypeA` or `DerivedTypeB` I have one particular type that is both `DerivedTypeA` and `DerivedTypeB`

When I seed the database by creating a new `DerivedTypeA` and `DerivedTypeB` for this type it gets added twice, with different `Id`s.  While not the end of the world, I'd like it to have the same `Id` in the two derived tables.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're describing a multiple-inheritance situation, which isn't supported in C#.  DerivedA cannot be DerivedB or vice-versa because they are siblings.

This article helps define the issue and presents a pattern which might help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/smip.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'm not sure it is a multiple inheritance situation - both DerivedA and DerivedB still only inherit from the one abstract class BaseType not multiple classes.

Comment: Yes but you've then said you have one type that is *both* DerivedA and DerivedB.  The only way for that to be possible in C# is if DerivedB derives from DerivedA (or the reverse) instead of both deriving from BaseType.

Comment: I accept your multiple inheritance point.  In the end I managed to restructure my data so that all types are either DerivedA or DerivedB and all now works as expected.  Thanks.